# Why does the trapezoid rule have error $\frac16(\Delta x)^2$ for $y=x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

We have $\int_0^{\Delta x}x^2dx=\frac13(\Delta x)^3$ and the trapezoid rule gives $\frac12(\Delta x)^3$ (see figure below). So the error is $\frac16(\Delta x)^3$. We also have $\int_{\Delta x}^{2\Delta x}x^2dx=\frac73(\Delta x)^3$ and the trapezoid rule gives $\frac52(\Delta x)^3$. The error is again $\frac16(\Delta x)^3$. Similarly, the error is $\frac16(\Delta x)^3$ for all the other intervals. Why do we say that the trapezoid rule has error $\frac16(\Delta x)^2$ for $y=x^2$?

[image: y=x^2 with trapezoids]

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis, in your case the second derivative is equal to 2.

Comment: The error $\frac{1}{6}(\Delta x)^2$ does not consider the length of the interval. If you multiply with the length of the interval, you get the correct error

Comment: In the end we don't care about $\int_0^{\Delta x}$, we care about $\int_a^b$ for some fixed $a$ and $b$. The error for one interval is $\frac16(\Delta x)^3$, but we need $O(1/\Delta x)$ intervals to cover a finite range $[a,b]$, so the *total* error is proportional to $\frac16(\Delta x)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Useful fact** $$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx=\frac{b-a}{2} [f(a)+f(b)]-\int_a^b \frac{(b-t)(t-a)}{2} f''(t)\, dt$$

Now $f''(t)=2$, $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$ $$E_T=-2\int_a^b \frac{(b-t)(t-a)}{2} dt=-\frac{(b-a)^3}{3}$$